# How to make a conditional manual approval in CircleCI 2.0 workflows

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, circleci, circleci-workflows

I have a simple use case where I want to make a [manual approval](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#holding-a-workflow-for-a-manual-approval) only for a specific branch and/or tag.

The workflow job with `type:approval` has filters like all other jobs but the job **foo** that requires a manual approval (or not) will use something like `requires: ['approve']` and then is strongly linked to it.

That means that **foo** will never happen at all if the approval step doesn't match the filter.

So.. any clean workaround, without many duplicates in yaml file?

Edit: [Same question on CircleCI Discuss](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/conditionally-require-a-manual-approval-workflow-step/16742)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Using [YAML alias map](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html)

This is kind of a hack but with [YAML alias map](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) you reuse your steps and make two separate workflow paths with different filters: One with approval and another one without.

Here is a full example:

```yaml
version: 2.0

# Run job (defined in a YAML alias map, see http://yaml.org/type/merge.html)
run-core: &run-core
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache: { key: 'xxxxx' }
      - run: npm install
      - save_cache: { key: 'xxxxx', paths: ['xxxx'] }
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm run validate
      - deploy: ./scripts/deploy.sh

# Jobs (duplicate the same job, but with different names)
jobs:
  run:
    <<: *run-core
  run-with-approval:
    <<: *run-core

# This will allow manual approval and context
# See https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#git-tag-job-execution
workflows:
  version: 2
  run:
    jobs:
      # Without approval (for all branches except staging)
      - run:
          context: org-global
          filters:
            branches: { ignore: 'staging' } # All branches except staging
            tags: { ignore: '/.*/' }        # Ignore all tags
      # With approval (only for tags and staging branch)
      - run-with-approval:
          context: org-global
          filters:
            tags: { only: '/.*/' }          # All branches and all tags
          requires: ['approve']             # But requires approval (which is filtering)
      - approve:
          type: approval
          filters:
            branches: { only: 'staging' }   # Ignore all branches except staging
            tags: { only: '/.*/' }          # All tags
```

I hope this will helps

Answer (score 3):

Updating this question with a more recent answer:
CircleCI has a v2 API in preview (to support CircleCI 2.1) which supports, among other things, conditional workflows (i.e. a conditional hold step)

[conditional workflow formatting](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/api-preview-docs/blob/master/docs/conditional-workflows.md)

```
- when:
    condition: << pipeline.parameters.test >>
    steps:
      - hold-step
```